# How to use Breeze Js with DevForce services

Tags: html, silverlight, asp.net-web-api, breeze, devforce

We have project developed in Silverlight/DevForce services, currently we plain to move code into HTML5. My question is it possible to reuse server side part of project, I means is it possible to reuse DevForce services or better migrate to WebAPI services? IdeaBlade has Breeze Js for HTML5, but it looks more as dataservice provider and not support DevForce services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be asking whether BreezeJS offers a mechanism for handling arbitrary service calls between the client and the Web API running on the server ... in the manner of the DevForce "invokeServerMethod".

BreezeJS **does not** .  The DevForce "invokeServerMethod" is helpful when you need to talk to the server for non-data reasons. You don't have to open and secure your own channel; instead you can share the DevForce secure data channel between client and server. It's also a convenient way to sent a package of entities. Setting up your own independent channel is not much fun.

But writing and communicating with a Web API service endpoint is much easier. Our thought is that you can manage your non-data communications quite well without the help of the BreezeJS EntityManager. So we don't see the need to implement the equivalent of "invokeServerMethod"

However, perhaps you have a scenario that would cause us to reconsider. We'd love to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze doesn't integrate with DevForce today. I'd recommend adding the request to the Breeze [UserVoice site](http://breezejs.uservoice.com). The Breeze team uses UserVoice to judge interest when incorporating new features.

A quick look shows me that there is already one DevForce related suggestion there: [Support for DevForce models](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3387673-support-devforce-models-).